# How to use Linq to set attributes based on counter

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Say I have a xml document that looks like this

```
<foo>
<bar id="9" />
<bar id="4" />
<bar id="3" />
</foo>
```

I would like to use linq to reset the id's to 0, 1 ,2.
What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XElement xml = GetXml();
var i = 0;
foreach (var e in xml.Elements("bar"))
  e.SetAttributeValue("id", i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with linq methods instead of foreach, but there isn't much bang for the buck:

```
XElement xml = GetXml();
int updatedElements = xml.Elements("bar")
    .Select((x, i) =>
    {
        x.SetAttributeValue("id", i);
        return x;
    })
    .Count();
```

Here, the Count() method is necessary  to enumerate the query.  Anything that enumerates the query would do.

If using the Select as a mutator bothers you (as it does me), use List(T).ForEach instead:

```
XElement xml = GetXml();
xml.Elements("bar")
    .Select( (x, i) => new {x, i})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(a => a.x.SetAttributeValue("id", a.i));
```

Comment: In most case, we can get more simple code than statement with query. But it seems not in this case.

Comment: Sure, Functional programming techniques are not so great at generating side-effects.